# How to get specific HTML or text in website in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

So I have this HTML website that has code like this:

```
<ul class="WCVH WKVH" role="list">
  <li class="WIUH" role="listitem">
    <div class="WKUH">
      <label id="labeledImage.POSTED_DATE--uid6-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="WMUH">
      <div class="WDBN WMP WDCN" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" id="labeledImage.POSTED_DATE--uid6">
        <div class="WIBN">
          <ul tabindex="-2" class="WCHJ WHBN" role="list" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
            <li class="WGHJ" role="presentation">
              <div class="WOGJ WFHJ" tabindex="-2" id="b7e15031a749444a855366b1f1a87a46" data-automation-id="menuItem" aria-label="Posted Today, press delete to clear value." role="listitem" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="1">
                <div class="WPGJ">
                  <div class="WACI">
                    <ul class="WCBI WIBI" role="presentation">
                      <li class="WPBI"><img class="gwt-Image WHWI WFPJ WKQJ" src="https://vps-wd5.myworkdaycdn.com/assets/ui-html/update/WorkdayApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" data-automation-id="POSTED_DATE_charm" alt="" aria-label=""
                        aria-labelledby="promptOption"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="gwt-Label WBCI" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption" title="Posted Today" aria-label="Posted Today" data-automation-label="Posted Today" aria-labelledby="labeledImage.POSTED_DATE--uid6-formLabel">Posted Today</div>
                    <ul class="WCBI"></ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="WIUH" role="listitem">
    <div class="WKUH">
      <label id="labeledImage.JOB_TYPE--uid7-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="WMUH">
      <div class="WDBN WMP WDCN" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" id="labeledImage.JOB_TYPE--uid7">
        <div class="WIBN">
          <ul tabindex="-2" class="WCHJ WHBN" role="list" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
            <li class="WGHJ" role="presentation">
              <div class="WOGJ WFHJ" tabindex="-2" id="5c6eda594d0d46609fa4c8e2ff13e731" data-automation-id="menuItem" aria-label="Full time, press delete to clear value." role="listitem" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="1">
                <div class="WPGJ">
                  <div class="WACI">
                    <ul class="WCBI WIBI" role="presentation">
                      <li class="WPBI"><img class="gwt-Image WHWI WFPJ WCQJ" src="https://vps-wd5.myworkdaycdn.com/assets/ui-html/update/WorkdayApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" data-automation-id="JOB_TYPE_charm" alt="" aria-label="" aria-labelledby="promptOption"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="gwt-Label WBCI" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption" title="Full time" aria-label="Full time" data-automation-label="Full time" aria-labelledby="labeledImage.JOB_TYPE--uid7-formLabel">Full time</div>
                    <ul class="WCBI"></ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="WIUH" role="listitem">
    <div class="WKUH">
      <label id="labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="WMUH">
      <div class="WDBN WMP WDCN" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" id="labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8">
        <div class="WIBN">
          <ul tabindex="-2" class="WCHJ WHBN" role="list" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
            <li class="WGHJ" role="presentation">
              <div class="WOGJ WFHJ" tabindex="-2" id="cc054d6cca664a3282855669711520d5" data-automation-id="menuItem" aria-label="T_R_1616417, press delete to clear value." role="listitem" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="1">
                <div class="WPGJ">
                  <div class="WACI">
                    <ul class="WCBI WIBI" role="presentation">
                      <li class="WPBI"><img class="gwt-Image WHWI WFPJ WBQJ" src="https://vps-wd5.myworkdaycdn.com/assets/ui-html/update/WorkdayApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" data-automation-id="JOB_REQ_charm" alt="" aria-label="" aria-labelledby="promptOption"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="gwt-Label WBCI" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption" title="T_R_1616417" aria-label="T_R_1616417" data-automation-label="T_R_1616417" aria-labelledby="labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8-formLabel">T_R_1616417</div>
                    <ul class="WCBI"></ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the specific Requisition ID: T_R_1616417 but I got error that they cannot find the ID in the div element tag.

Error Code

```
`An unhandled exception of type 'WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException' occurred in WatiN.Core.dll

Additional information: Could not find DIV element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'id' equals 'labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8' at https://hpe.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/Jobsathpe/job/BEP01---Embassy-Prime-BEP01/AMS-Profiling-Data-Specialist_1000713
`
```

Here's my code in C# in grabbing the specific item:

`reqID = browser.Div(Find.ById("labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8")).OuterText.ToString();`

How can i get the correct value "T_R_1616417" in this line of html code in C# format?

Comment: In the future please format your code so that it is readable. A single line of HTML makes it hard to scan to see if the id exists!

Comment: Is this `div` element you want to extract `T_R_1616417` value: `<div class="gwt-Label WBCI" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption" title="T_R_1616417" aria-label="T_R_1616417" data-automation-label="T_R_1616417" aria-labelledby="labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8-formLabel">T_R_1616417</div>`, or `<div class="WDBN WMP WDCN" data-automation-id="responsiveMonikerInput" id="labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8">`?

Comment: I would also avoid using `.` in your ID attribute if you can avoid it as this will cause issues with CSS and jquery selectors, with `.` denoting the start of a class name.

Comment: Yes but the problem as you see there are multiple class that has those div. so what I'm getting sometimes are the Requisition title and dates or locations

Comment: I need to get this value = T_R_1‌​616417

Comment: If you are generating the HTML you need to be aware ID needs to be unique for the document/page. In the sampe you have give there are 3 examples of `id="promptOption"`. Replicated `id` will not be helping you here.

Comment: yes and that's my problem, that's why I'm using the labeledImage.JOB_REQ--uid8 ID cause that's the only unique on those items. all other classes and are all the same, that's my major problem here, so how can i tell which class and which element should I use?